# import datadump in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I having two database versions: 12c and 18c in my system.  I tried to import the dump file to database version 18c, when I run the impdp command in cmd, it's connecting to oracle database 12c.  How to import the dump file to database version 18c. Please advise me.

Below is following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32>impdp DBBEND_LIFE_ESUBMISSION/oracle@orcl18c directory=DMP_DIRECTORY dumpfile=DBBEND_LIFE_ESUBMISSION.DMP logfile=err.log
```

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Sep 5 16:42:06 2019
Version 18.3.0.0.0

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-39087: directory name DMP_DIRECTORY is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `connect identifier` in the connect string when you invoke the Data Pump Import utility. 
The `connect identifier` can be an **Oracle*Net connect descriptor** or a name that maps to a connect descriptor. This requires an active listener (to start the listener, enter lsnrctl start) that can be located using the connect descriptor.

The local Import client connects to the database instance identified by the connect descriptor.

So make sure that in your case Connect descriptor (@orcl18c) is representing the correct version of your oracle instance.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. tns.ora file contains same port number 1521 for 12c and 18c.  I changed the corresponding port number to 1522 in 18c tns.ora file and also i changed listener alias name to listener2 in 18cversion. And then i start Isnrctl service. Data imported successsfully to 18c version.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your current "default" listener. It's really not clear, but my solution (for my problems) was found on [Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_import.htm#BEHDGDBG) in network consideration section.

Answer (score 1):

I find the cited oracle doc to be rather poorly written.  All you need to do to insure that your expdp or impdp operation connects to the correct database is specify the tns connect string on the command line:

`c:> impdp myuser/mypassword@mydb .....`.

where 'mydb' is a net service name listed in the client's tnsnames.ora file. If you don't want to include the password on the command line, leave that part out and you will be prompted for it.

Also let me comment that it appears that your understanding of the role of the listner and ports is incorrect.  There is no binding of a particular database to a particular port.  One single listener, using the default name of LISTENER and the default port of 1521, is quite capable of -- indeed, WAS DESIGNED TO -- service multiple databases of multiple versions running from multiple homes.  Even IF you have configured a single listener to listen on multiple ports, there is no connection between a particular port and a particular database being serviced by that listener.  In reality there is no reason to have multiple listeners, and there is no reason to have your one single listener use any port other than the default of 1521.